# jquery conditions separated by commas

Tags: jquery

I was just dissecting some code and I came across a line that I didn't understand.

```
    function removeClasses() {
       $(".bar").removeClass("active"), 
       $(".bar .player-info").removeClass("active"), 
       $(".list").removeClass("active")
    }
    function addClasses(){
       $(".bar").addClass("active"), 
       $(".list").addClass("active"), 
       $(".bar .player-info").addClass("active")
    }
    function initWaypoint(a) { 
    if($(".list li").removeClass("active"),addClasses(),-1==a)removeClasses();
    else{
    ...
    }
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".list li").waypoint(function(direction) {
    initWaypoint("down" == direction ? $(this.element).index() : $(this.element).index()-1);
    }, { offset: '30%' });
});
```

Hopefully this is enough, I didn't think I'd need to show html.  The line I'm most interested in is;

```
if($(".list li").removeClass("active"),addClasses(),-1==a)removeClasses();
```

I just don't understand how this works.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN:

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

This code looks like it went through a minifier. I can't fathom why someone would write it like this.

The line

```
if($(".list li").removeClass("active"),addClasses(),-1==a)removeClasses();
```

is equivalent to:

```
$(".list li").removeClass("active");
addClasses();
if(a == -1) {
  removeClasses();
}
```